# Routing Polymorphic Requests Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

In rails 3, I have several polymorphic models such as `Image` and `Comment`, so my question is,

When someone makes a request to Create/Update/Destroy a polymorphic object, should the request go to a single controller for the polymorphic object `CommentController`, or should the request be routed to the controller of the polymorphic accessor i.e. `StatusController` or `ImageController`?

The pros of a single controller are that it is more DRY and probably more RESTful, the bad thing is that it feels to me like it couples the application more, where many things are tied together by one single controller. Does anyone have an official answer to this question?

EDIT: The question is NOT asking where the route goes, the question is asking **where should the route go? What is the most semantic solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

You should let comment controller handle CRUD actions on comments. Your original argument for it is correct that this way is more DRY and RESTful. Extra logistics the comment controller have to handle isn't that complex, so you should still be left with relatively thin comment controller. If you are still concerned about the actions in comment controller getting to fat, you can abstract away some of the logic by writing methods in comment model to handle some of the logic.

Comment: When you say, `a polymorphic object`, are you referring to a `comment`? How are the three objects mentioned above associated with each other?

Comment: statuses and images both have comments. Which controller should handle comment requests?